# Google analytics, emulate campaign hit serverside

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I am involved in a project where people needed to link + track users going to a third party site.

They did this by setting up a redirect page that funnels users on to the third party site, while setting up tracking using Google analytics and building campaign urls that point to the redirect page.

I want to set up a quicker redirect page by handling the analytics serverside. It speeds up well, but to be able to transition, I need to somehow emulate passing through their pass through page.

I'm using asp net core, but this should be fairly lagnuage agnostic, since I'm using the google api

```
    [HttpGet]
    public RedirectResult Get()
    {
        [...]

        //send official analytics async
        Task.Run(() => SendParametersToGoogle(BuildPageViewUrl(_config["officialAnalyticsId"], _config["officialRedirectUrl"], "TCI", source, medium)));

        return Redirect(_config["redirectUrl"]);
    }

    private static string BuildPageViewUrl(string googleId, string documentLocation, string campaignName, string campaignSource, string campaignMedium)
        => $"v=1&tid={UrlEncode(googleId)}&t=pageview&dl={UrlEncode(documentLocation)}" +
           $"&cn={UrlEncode(campaignName)}&cs={UrlEncode(campaignSource)}&cm={UrlEncode(campaignMedium)}";

    private static void SendParametersToGoogle(string parameters) => HttpClient.PostAsync(new Uri("https://www.google-analytics.com/collect"), new StringContent(parameters, Encoding.ASCII));
```

I get an OK response, but the events doesn't show up in google analytics under Acquisition->Campaigns->All Campaigns.

I have waited 3 days to allow for data processing time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your generated call to the Measurement Protocol seem to be missing [Client ID](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cid) or [User ID](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#uid). The documentation claims one of them as required, to identify the visitor.

I'm not sure, why you get successful response, as Client ID is also marked as a mandatory field by the [Hit Builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/) tool:

[image]